# Issue when using FMOD library

Tags: c, fmod

I'm trying to retrieve the sound spectrum with the FMOD Studio LowLevel library. However, it seems that the `FMOD_Channel_GetSpectrum()` function has been removed from the library, and I can't find any other version that have this function.

Does anyone know where I can find the good version of the library, or which other library can do the same?

Answer (score 1):

["FMOD Ex and FMOD Designer are currently in maintenance mode and are no longer actively developed."](http://www.fmod.org/download/).

This library is not longer downloadable if you don't buy it before.

You could find some site that propose the old library but I don't recommend because it's not official. So It can hide anything.

You should read the [migration guide](http://www.fmod.org/documentation/#content/generated/overview/transitioning.html).

> **System::getSpectrum and System::getWaveData removed**
>
> Add a custom DSP unit to capture DSP wavedata from the output stage.
>   Use the master channelgroup's DSP head with
>   System::getMasterChannelGroup and ChannelControl::getDSP.
>
> Add a built
>   in FFT DSP unit type to capture spectrum data from the output stage.
>   Create a built in FFT unit with System::createDSPByType and
>   FMOD_DSP_TYPE_FFT, then add the effect to the master ChannelGroup with
>   ChannelGroup::addDSP. Use DSP::getParameterData to get the raw
>   spectrum data or use DSP::getParameterFloat to get the dominant
>   frequency from the signal.